# Is there a python equivalent for R's h2o.stack?

Tags: python, r, h2o, ensemble-learning

I am working with stacked learners. According to the docs for [H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html) h2o's python implementation allows you to easily build ensemble models. However this is limited to building base classifiers with the same underlying training data. I have time based features whose minimum date varies depending on the data source. Each sample of data is a point in time. To take advantage of as much data as I can, I split the features up until two groups (depending on relevance and minimum date) and train two separate models. I would like to combine these models, but H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator requires the features to be the same.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408295/what-is-the-different-between-h2o-ensemble-and-h2o-stack-in-package-h2oensemble) about R's stacked ensemble implementation there is an option to only perform the metalearning step which should require only the k-fold cross-validation predicitons for each base model and the true target value.

In case it crosses anyone's mind...for my particular problem, I realize I am going to run into an issue with the metalearning step with this mismatch in minimum date, and I have ideas to circumvent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [Super Learner](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html#super-learner-algorithm) algorithm (stacking such that you use the cross-validated predicted values from the base learners as training data for the metalearner), the only requirement is that the base learners must be trained on the same rows -- the columns can be different.  There is a variant of stacking, let's call it ["Holdout Stacking"](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4680), where you score the base models on a holdout dataset and use those predictions to train the metalearner instead.  In this case, you can use entirely different training frames for the base learners.

The current [Stacked Ensembles](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html) implementation in H2O has a restriction that the whole training frame (rows and columns) must be the same for the base learners, but we [will relax that requirement](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4679) in the future (since it's not really required).

Before we moved Stacked Ensembles in to the Java backend of H2O, I coded a simple reference implementation in Python using only the **h2o** Python module.  For the time being, you could probably modify that code fairly easily to get the type of Stacked Ensemble that you're looking for.  It's in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/ledell/3d99498d4236248f9bfbc8ed2fd424fa).

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks!